# Assets not working in produciton

Tags: jquery, ruby, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

For some reason my assets work and load up correctly in development env but, in production this isn't the case.

I ran `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

I also tried `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Distro Xububntu 14.04.1 LTS

Rails 4.1.1 
Ruby 1.9.3

This is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.2'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.2'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

gem 'jquery-scrollto-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-sass-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'jquery-timepicker-rails'

gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'sdoc', require: false
gem 'ruby-oci8'
gem "activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter", "~> 1.5.0"

gem 'audited-activerecord', '~> 4.0.0.rc1'
gem 'nested_form'
gem 'composite_primary_keys'
#gem 'mysql'

gem 'capistrano'
gem 'html2haml'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
gem 'whenever', :require => false

gem 'airbrake'
gem 'net-ssh', '~> 2.6.8'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'devise'

gem 'cancan'
gem 'kaminari'

# Angular stuff
gem 'angularjs-rails'
gem 'ng-rails-csrf'
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
gem 'angular-ui-bootstrap-rails'

# Testing
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'teaspoon'
gem 'phantomjs'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'

#--Need Istanbul node package installed for JS coverage reporting to work
gem 'simplecov'


# Nice stack trace
#gem 'better_errors'
gem 'binding_of_caller'

# Clean server logs
gem 'quiet_assets'
gem 'webrick'
```

This is my application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all    
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require tmpl.js
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require jquery.timepicker.js
//= require report
//= require stats
//= require record
//= require uploads
```

This is my Production Env configs

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true


   # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true 

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  config.assets.compress = true 

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Comment: *"I ran [...] I also tried [...]"* - what happened? Any errors?

Comment: No errors it compiled all of my assets with no errors, it works in development but, none of the jquery effects work in production like (datepicker, timepicker, etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the stuff that isnt working in production is all of jQuery assets